# @SpringBean doesnt work when accessing page with @MountedPath

Tags: spring-boot, wicket

I'm using com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter.wicket-spring-boot-starter with SpringBoot 1.5.x . Unfortunately I'm gettings errors when using Spring beans injections using `@SpringBean` annotation. (I'm using wicket common demo with home, first and second page) Its working (bean injection) fine when accessing page using common url: /wicket/bookmarkable/app.wicket.pages.FirstPage . But this page has also annotation @MountPath and when accessing page using URL defined in this annotation I'm gettings error as below. Is there any specific option that enables Spring injection for `@MountPath` pages? Btw. I'm using latest stable wicket-spring-boot-starter 1.0.6 version (the same problem with 2.0.1 version using Wicket 8M5) ... Any idea whats wrong ?

```
Unexpected RuntimeException

Last cause: Concrete bean could not be received from the application context for class: app.spring.DataService.
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public app.wicket.pages.FirstPage()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!

Stacktrace

Root cause:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Concrete bean could not be received from the application context for class: app.spring.DataService.
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringBeanLocator.lookupSpringBean(SpringBeanLocator.java:277)
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringBeanLocator.locateProxyTarget(SpringBeanLocator.java:198)
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.getFieldValue(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:150)
     at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:111)
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.inject(SpringComponentInjector.java:124)
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.onInstantiation(SpringComponentInjector.java:130)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:38)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:34)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.notify(ListenerCollection.java:80)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.onInstantiation(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:33)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.<init>(Component.java:688)
     at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.<init>(MarkupContainer.java:178)
     at org.apache.wicket.Page.<init>(Page.java:170)
     at org.apache.wicket.Page.<init>(Page.java:134)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.<init>(WebPage.java:74)
     at app.wicket.pages.BasePage.<init>(BasePage.java:8)
     at app.wicket.pages.FirstPage.<init>(FirstPage.java:31)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:90)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:280)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:169)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:287)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:333)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:193)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:912)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:262)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:204)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:286)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Complete stack:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public app.wicket.pages.FirstPage()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:90)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:280)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:169)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:287)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:333)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:193)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:912)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:262)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:90)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:280)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:169)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:287)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:333)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:193)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:912)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:262)
```

Comment: Are you using spring-boot-devtools? Can you remove it and try it again?

Comment: Really, disabling DevTools makes it work correctly. What does it mean? DevTools is necessary tool for development ...

Comment: The problem is the restart functionality of Spring Boot Devtools. There is a classloading issue of the wicket libraries. I'll provide a fix to fully support the @MountPath annotations. [Spring Boot Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a *META-INF/spring-devtools.properties* file in the root classpath with the following content:

```
restart.include.wicket-annotation=/wicketstuff-annotation-[\\w-\.]+\.jar
restart.include.wicket-spring=/wicket-spring-[\\w-\.]+\.jar
```

This tells Spring Boot Devtools to reload the Wicket classes in the defined jars after restart.

I'll update the Wicket Spring Boot Starter project. With the next release you don't have to provide this property anymore.

Comment: Full spring-devtools.properties file example is here https://github.com/MarcGiffing/wicket-spring-boot/blob/dd3146f9009dff454fbd500686677f901598b2c9/wicket-spring-boot-starter/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-devtools.properties